# Strange JSON response (" "=> ,) in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, response

I'm getting a json response from the forecast.io api with

```
JSON.parse(open("https://api.forecast.io/forecast/api-key/latitude,longitude").read)
```

And it looks like this

```
{"latitude"=>58.5942, 
 "longitude"=>16.1826, 
 "timezone"=>"Europe/Stockholm", 
 "offset"=>2, 
 "currently"=>{
   "time"=>1367829429, 
   "summary"=>"Clear", 
   "icon"=>"clear-day", 
   "precipIntensity"=>0, 
   "temperature"=>59.04, 
   "dewPoint"=>41.6, 
   "windSpeed"=>11.49, 
   "windBearing"=>224, 
   "cloudCover"=>0.08, 
   "humidity"=>0.53, 
   "pressure"=>1022.88, 
   "visibility"=>6.21, 
   "ozone"=>319.4
 }
```

I'm new to json but this is not regular json right? What should I do to get this to my view in script  tags?

Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not a valid JSON.

Comment: it looks like regular json but it's missing a closing `}` (which you may have forgot to copy in)

Comment: sorry, this is just a bit of the whole response, I just didn't want to include it all =)

Answer (score 0):

Use the particular JSON Keymap you want in the call, and return it in the JSON request callback function. I believe that would resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

response = HTTParty.get('https://api.forecast.io/forecast/api-key/latitude,longitude', {:timeout => 3})

@currenttemp = response["temp"]

it will return in a json object because it detects it is JSON. (HTTParty is just a helper gem)